# Android progressbar long param

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have two Date objects. EndDate and StartDate.
I want to show difference(including hours and minutes) between this dates in progressbar.
I initialized two long variables with Date.getTime() and then calculated difference.

But ProgressBar.setProgress() and ProgressBar.setMax() accept only int.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` is a integer type. You can cast without issue if the difference does not exceed the `int` size.

A `long` che holds  `2^(63-1)` values, an `int` `2^(31-1).` If the value you are setting through `setMax()` you can cast it to `int` without issue.

Comment: @user1766287 case as an integer (if it does not exceed the int size). then just call `setMax()` with your int..